# Prepend headers to my c# excel output file

Tags: c#, sql, excel, winforms

I have this block of code and want to insert headers before it writes. I have tried various ways but it keeps reading and mixing the headers with the data being written to file. I tried adding the heading outside the if block but it still makes no difference, I also tried adding it right after the file is created but same result.  I would like to know how to add it without it mixing with the data

```
  using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter("cross_check.xls", true))
        {

            if (stream == null)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("File can't be written");

            }

            else  
            {

                stream.WriteLine();
                stream.Write(search.Text);
                stream.Write("\t ");
                stream.Write(textBox1.Text);

                MessageBox.Show("Data Added Successfully");

            }
```

Comment: I would have shown you a screenshot but let me try explaining: The contents of it are the data that is being written to it without the headers. When I try to include the headers before hand they mix with the data. So for eg. I would have Code and Description as the headers(two column of data being written) when I add let's say "cat" it goes below "code" and let's say I add "dog" it goes under "Description" but when I add more data the result is that of the headers duplicating and moving beside any data that was added

Comment: You can create a DataTable and use interop to create excel file from it. So Headers will be same as DataTable headers.

Comment: Does your `xls` file contains text format? Do you want to just add a new line  like `Id, Name, Description, Something else` at the beginning of file?

Comment: Yes i just want to  to add a new line of those value types before data begins to be written

Comment: So take a look at answer.

Comment: I did not see it. Damn an missing a lot I'll take a look when am home. On the road now

Comment: @Jevon No problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the header when you write data to file. But if you have some existing files which need modification and if the content of your excel file is text contents (which seems to be, based on the question), you can simply use `File.ReadAllLines` and `File.WriteAllLines` this way:

```
var file = @"d:\file.xls";
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();
lines.Insert(0, "Some text");
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
```

Using `File.ReadAllLines` you have all lines of your file and you can perform additional processing on file contents too. For example you can split all lines by a delimiter and manipulate each cell or add new columns and so on. Also you can shape the result into a data structure like `DataTable` and show it in `DataGridView` to edit them and save them back to the file again.

Comment: I only need it to write to the file so the ReadAllLines not really needed so am guessing it could be done like this:

`
        string path = @"Test.txt";

        // This text is added only once to the file.
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
         .
            string[] createText = { "Code", "Description", "NDC" };
            File.WriteAllLines(path, createText);
        }`

Comment: ReadAllLines is used because you said `Prepend`, so the answer suppose you have some content in file, if you don't have, it doesn't mean prepending its just saving some text in file.

Comment: I still haven't gotten the grasp of commenting code blocks. Sorry about the text above

Comment: Remove the space after "`" character at beginning of your code block.

Comment: ohhh Thanks. Finally got it